# Using a dictionary instead of a list to manage a collection

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, collections

I am trying to use a dictionary to manage a collection instead of a list. The use case is for a program that manages a card collection. I have functional code for using a list, but I am seeking assistance with updating the functions to use a dictionary instead. When attempting to use a dictionary, I am getting a TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable message in reference to the print('ID: {0}'.format(target['ID'])) line.

In this case, I am trying to get the display_cards function to work and I would appreciate assistance with troubleshooting. I believe the load_card_collection_file function needs to be updated, and particularly the card_collection[card_collection_item["ID"]] = card_collection_item line.

```
    def load_card_collections():

    sports_card_collection, max_sport_id = load_collection("sportscards.csv")
    pokemon_cards_collection, max_poke_id = load_collection("pokecards.csv")

    if sports_card_collection_collection is None or pokemon_cards_collection_collection is None:
        return None, None

    return {"sports": sports_card_collection, "pokemon": pokemon_cards_collection}, max(max_sport_id, max_poke_id)


def load_card_collection_file(file_name):
    max_id = -1
    try:
        card_collection = {} # This would be changed to a list in the functioning code
        
        card_collection_file = open(file_name, "r")
        field_names = card_collection_file.readline().rstrip().split(",")

        for item in card_collection_file:
            field_values = item.rstrip().split(",")
            card_collection_item = {}
            for index in range(len(field_values)):
                if (field_names[index] == "Available") or (field_names[index] == "Copies") or (field_names[index] == "ID"):
                    collection_item[field_names[index]] = int(field_values[index])
                else:
                    collection_item[field_names[index]] = field_values[index]
            card_collection[card_collection_item["ID"]] = card_collection_item 

            max_id = max(max_id, card_collection_item["ID"]) 

        card_collection_file.close()

    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("File not found when attempting to read", file_name)
        return None
    except IOError:
        print("Error in data file when reading", file_name)
        return None

    return card_collection, max_id


def menu_prompts():
    print("Command      Function")
    print("  cci        Check in an card")
    print("  cco        Check out an card")
    print("  asc        Add a new sports card")
    print("  apc        Add a new pokemon card")
    print("  dsc        Display sports cards")
    print("  dpc        Display pokemon cards")
    print("  qsc        Query for sports cards")
    print("  qpc        Query for pokemon cards")
    print("  x          Exit")
    return input("Enter a command: ")

def main():

    card_library_collections, max_existing_id = load_card_collections()

    if card_library_collections is None:
        print("The collections did not load.")
        return
    else:
        print("The collections were loaded.")


    operation = menu_prompts()
    while operation != "x":
    # The function calls would need to be updated in this list
        if operation == "cci":
            check_in(card_library_collections)
        elif operation == "cco":
            check_out(card_library_collections)
        elif operation == "asc":
            max_existing_id = add_sports_card(library_collections["sports"], max_existing_id)
        elif operation == "apc":
            max_existing_id = add_pokemon_card(library_collections["pokemon"], max_existing_id)
        elif operation == "dsc":
            display_cards(card_library_collections["sports"])
        elif operation == "dpc":
            display_cards(card_library_collections["pokemon"])
        elif operation == "qsc":
            query_cards(card_library_collections["sports"])
        elif operation == "qpc":
            query_cards(card_library_collections["pokemon"])
        else:
            print("Invalid command")

        operation = menu_prompts()

def check_in(card_library_collections):

    card_id = int(input('Enter the ID for the card: '))
    library = card_library_collections['sports'] + card_library_collections['pokemon']

    for idx, item in enumerate(library):
        if item['ID'] != card_id:
            continue
        elif item['Available'] < item['Copies']:
            library[idx]['Available'] += 1
            print('Your check in has succeeded.')
            display_cards([library[idx]], sports_or_pokemon(library, idx))
            return
        elif item['Available'] == item['Copies']:
            print('All copies are already available, so this card cannot be checked in.')
            return
        else:
            print('Your card ID is invalid')

def check_out(card_library_collections):

    card_id = int(input('Enter the ID for the card you wish to check out: '))
    library = card_library_collections['sports'] + card_library_collections['pokemon']

    for idx, item in enumerate(library):
        if item['ID'] != card_id:
            continue
        elif item['Available'] > 0:
            library[idx]['Available'] -= 1
            print('Your check out has succeeded.')
            display_cards([library[idx]], sports_or_pokemon(library, idx))
            return
        elif item['Available'] == 0:
            print('No copies of the card are available for check out.')
            return
        else:
            print('Your card ID is invalid,')

def sports_or_pokemon(library, idx):

    return 'Sport' in library[idx]

def query_cards(card_collection, sports_or_pokemon_query):

    query_str = input('Enter a query string to use for the search: ')

    if len(query_str) == 0:
        print('Invalid query string.')
        return

    card_list = []
    query_str = query_str.lower()
    for idx, item in enumerate(card_collection):
        if (sports_or_pokemon_query and (query_str in item['Name'].lower() or query_str in item['Sport'].lower() or query_str in item['Publisher'].lower())):
            card_list.append(item)
        elif (not sports_or_pokemon_query and (query_str in item['Title'].lower() or query_str in item['Edition'].lower() or query_str in item['Generation'].lower())):
            card_list.append(item)

    display_cards(res, sports_or_pokemon_query)

def add_sports_card(card_library_collections, max_existing_id):


    print('Please enter the following attributes for the new sports card.')
    card_collection_list = {}

    max_existing_id += 1
    card_collection_list['ID'] = max_existing_id
    card_collection_list['Name'] = input('Name: ')
    card_collection_list['Sport'] = input('Sport: ')
    card_collection_list['Publisher'] = input('Publisher: ')
    card_collection_list['Series'] = input('Series: ')
    card_collection_list['Year'] = int(input('Year: '))
    card_collection_list['Copies'] = int(input('Copies: '))
    card_collection_list['Available'] = card_collection_list['Copies']

    print('You have entered the following details:')
    display_cards([card_collection_list], True)


    cancel_prompt = input("Press enter to add this item to the collection. Enter 'x' to cancel.")
    if(not cancel_prompt):
        card_library_collectionslibrary_collections['sports'].append(card_collection_item)
        return max_existing_id
    elif(cancel_prompt == 'x'):
        return max_existing_id - 1

def add_pokemon_card(card_library_collections, max_existing_id):
    print('Please enter the following attributes for the new card.')
    card_collection_list = {}

    max_existing_id += 1
    card_collection_list['ID'] = max_existing_id
    card_collection_list['Name'] = input('Name: ')
    card_collection_list['Edition'] = input('Edition: ')
    card_collection_list['Rarity'] = input('Rarity: ')
    card_collection_list['Generation'] = input('Generation: ')
    card_collection_list['Year'] = int(input('Year: '))
    card_collection_list['Copies'] = int(input('Copies: '))
    card_collection_list['Available'] = card_collection_list['Copies']

    print('You have entered the following data:')
    display_cards([card_collection_item], False)

    cancel_prompt = input("Press enter to add this item to the collection. Enter 'x' to cancel.")
    if(not cancel_prompt):
        card_library_collections['pokemon'].append(card_collection_item)
        return max_existing_id
    elif(cancel_prompt == 'x'):
        return max_existing_id - 1

def display_cards(items, sports_or_pokemon):

    if len(items) == 0 and sports_or_pokemon:
        print('No related sports cards are found.')
    elif len(items) == 0 and not sports_or_pokemon:
        print('No related pokemon cards are found.')
    else:
        for target in items:
            print('ID: {0}'.format(target['ID']))
            print('Name: {0}'.format(target['Name']))
            print('Year: {0}'.format(target['Year']))
            print('Copies: {0}'.format(target['Copies']))
            print('Available: {0}'.format(target['Available']))

            if(sports_or_pokemon):
                print('Sport: {0}'.format(target['Sport']))
                print('Publisher: {0}'.format(target['Publisher']))
                print('Series: {0}'.format(target['Series']))
            else:
                print('Edition: {0}'.format(target['Edition']))
                print('Rarity: {0}'.format(target['Rarity']))
                print('Generation: {0}'.format(target['Generation']))
            print('')

main()
```

Comment: The error tells you, that at least one element in `items` is a integer instad of a dict, therefore `target['ID']` cannot be done.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Does this imply that eliminating any instances of integer items would resolve the issue?